# Gradle "Unable to resolve org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.0.6.RELEASR"

Tags: spring, maven, gradle

Recently learning spring official tutorial.

In the "Accessing Relational Data using JDBC with Spring" example:

I imported the project and found the following problem.

```
Unable to resolve org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.0.6.RELEASR
```

[image]

How to solve this warning?

Comment: It's `org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.0.6.RELEASE` and not `org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.0.6.RELEASR`

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni 
Thank you, but my code is correct.